# What is the use of constructor return value in java and how to access this value?

Tags: java, constructor

As JDK 8 allows return type of constructor and also allows to return a value from constructor so what is the use of it?
How to access return value of constructor in below program?

```
public class ConstructorReturn {
    int ConstructorReturn() {
        return 10;
    }
    public static void main(String... args) {
        ConstructorReturn constructorReturn = new ConstructorReturn();
    }
}
```

Comment: That's not a constructor. That's a method named like a constructor.

Comment: "As JDK 8 allows return type of constructor ..." - This is not true, constructors cannot have a return type, and there is no such feature as of JDK 8.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
int ConstructorReturn()
{
   return 10;
}
```

That's not a constructor. It's a regular method having the same name as the class. A constructor has no return value.

A constructor will never have a return value (not even void) :

```
ConstructorReturn()
{

}
```

Your `ConstructorReturn constructorReturn=new ConstructorReturn();` line doesn't invoke your `ConstructorReturn` method. It invokes the a default parameterless constructor that was generated by the compiler, since your class didn't have any explicit constructors.

Answer (score 3):

I don't see a constructor here.

You have a method that returns an `int` and has the same name as the class:

```
int ConstructorReturn() {
   return 10;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int ConstructorReturn()
{
   return 10;
}
```

Is not a constructor, it is a method that returns an int of 10

Not specifying anything has a specific meaning:

- public - any class can access this member protected - subclasses can
  access this member (as well as code in the same class or in the same
  package)
- private - only code in the same class can access this member
- nothing ("default" access) - only code in the same package can access
  this member

Comment: Visibility is not relevant to the question.

Comment: Just specifying the visibility since he seemed to have mistaken default access for a constructor

Comment: We can use by making constructor to static modifer.

Comment: Run above solution it will run constructor.